# How to avoid repeated tuples in Flink slide window join?

Tags: apache-flink

For example, there are two streams. One is advertisements showed to users. The tuple in which could be described as (advertiseId, showed timestamp). The other one is click stream -- (advertiseId, clicked timestamp). We want get a joined stream, which includes all the advertisement that is clicked by user in 20 minutes after showed. My solution is to join these two streams on a SlidingTimeWindow. But in the joined stream, there are many repeated tuples. How could I get joined tuple only one in new stream?

```
stream1.join(stream2)
        .where(0)
        .equalTo(0)
        .window(SlidingTimeWindows.of(Time.of(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES), Time.of(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution 1:

Let flink support join two streams on separate windows like Spark streaming. In this case, implement SlidingTimeWindows(21 mins, 1 min) on advertisement stream and TupblingTimeWindows(1 min) on Click stream, then join these two windowed streams.

TupblingTimeWindows could avoid duplicate records in the joined stream.
21 mins size SlidingTimeWindows could avoid missing legal clicks.
One issue is there would be some illegal click(click after 20 mins) in the joined stream. This problem could be fixed easily by adding a filter.

```
MultiWindowsJoinedStreams<Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple2<String, Long>> joinedStreams =
            new MultiWindowsJoinedStreams<>(advertisement, click);

    DataStream<Tuple3<String, Long, Long>> joinedStream = joinedStreams.where(keySelector)
            .window(SlidingTimeWindows.of(Time.of(21, TimeUnit.SECONDS), Time.of(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .equalTo(keySelector)
            .window(TumblingTimeWindows.of(Time.of(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .apply(new JoinFunction<Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple3<String, Long, Long>>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -3625150954096822268L;

                @Override
                public Tuple3<String, Long, Long> join(Tuple2<String, Long> first, Tuple2<String, Long> second) throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple3<>(first.f0, first.f1, second.f1);
                }
            });

    joinedStream = joinedStream.filter(new FilterFunction<Tuple3<String, Long, Long>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4325256210808325338L;

        @Override
        public boolean filter(Tuple3<String, Long, Long> value) throws Exception {
            return value.f1<value.f2&&value.f1+20000>=value.f2;
        }
    });
```

Solution 2:

Flink supports join operation without window. A join operator implement the interface TwoInputStreamOperator keeps two buffers(time length based) of these two streams and output one joined stream.

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Long>> advertisement = env
            .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<String>("advertisement", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))
            .map(new MapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Long>>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -6564495005753073342L;

                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, Long> map(String value) throws Exception {
                    String[] splits = value.split(" ");
                    return new Tuple2<String, Long>(splits[0], Long.parseLong(splits[1]));
                }
            }).keyBy(keySelector).assignTimestamps(timestampExtractor1);

    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Long>> click = env
            .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<String>("click", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))
            .map(new MapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Long>>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -6564495005753073342L;

                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, Long> map(String value) throws Exception {
                    String[] splits = value.split(" ");
                    return new Tuple2<String, Long>(splits[0], Long.parseLong(splits[1]));
                }
            }).keyBy(keySelector).assignTimestamps(timestampExtractor2);

    NoWindowJoinedStreams<Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple2<String, Long>> joinedStreams =
            new NoWindowJoinedStreams<>(advertisement, click);
    DataStream<Tuple3<String, Long, Long>> joinedStream = joinedStreams
            .where(keySelector)
            .buffer(Time.of(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .equalTo(keySelector)
            .buffer(Time.of(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .apply(new JoinFunction<Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple3<String, Long, Long>>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -5075871109025215769L;

                @Override
                public Tuple3<String, Long, Long> join(Tuple2<String, Long> first, Tuple2<String, Long> second) throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple3<>(first.f0, first.f1, second.f1);
                }
            });
```

I implemented two new join operators base on Flink streaming API TwoInputTransformation. Please check [Flink-stream-join](https://github.com/wangyangjun/flink-stream-join). I will add more tests to this repository.

Comment: Cool solution! Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: Pretty cool. However, link only answers are considered bad practice at SO. Can you extend your answer?

Comment: Thanks, I will extend it and do more tests on my solutions.

Comment: Base on the second solution, I create an issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-3109. Anyone could help to vote and assign this task to me?

Answer (score 1):

On your code, you defined an overlapping sliding window (slide is smaller than window size). If you don't want to have duplicates you can define a non-overlapping window by only specifying the window size (the default slide is equal to the window size).

Comment: There is one problem with a non-overlapping window in this case. If there is a advertise tuple at then end of first window, while the corresponding click tuple is at the begin of the second window. Then in the joined stream, there would be some data missing.

Comment: I see your point. However, you could miss matching tuples if you use a slide of 10 seconds, too, if a tuple of the first 10 seconds in a window would match a tuple is last 10 seconds of the next window. To not miss any matching tuple, you need to build a 30 second window for with a slide of *one tuple*. To avoid duplicates, you could also specify an `Evictor`: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/streaming_guide.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Time window with a slide of one tuple makes sense to me. While it seems that I couldn't avoid duplicates with an Evictor.

Comment: Maybe you can use a `cogroup` instead of join. Using CoGroup gives you an iterator over the windows of both inputs that should be joined. The internal join implementation does a nested-loop within a cogroup to compute the join. If you implements you own cogroup function, we might be able to avoid duplicates... If this does not work either, what about a duplicate elimination step after the join (even if this in quite ugly)?

Comment: If the duplicates are from the same window, then CoGroup could solve this problem. But in my case, it is because same data would be in different windows and joined to the same result. How to implement such a duplicate elimination step?

Comment: This depends heavily on you application. First, you need to be able to identify duplicates in the first place. Second, you would need to "remember" if you have seen a tuples already or not and drop the duplicates (maybe you could use a `Map` and Flink's `OperatorState`?). Last, you need to know how long to keep the information of the first emitted tuples (after a while, there cannot be any more duplicates) in order to avoid the state you remember to grow infinitely.

Comment: Maybe window-reduce could also help to filter duplicates -- ie, build a window that contains all duplicates -- if the "head" tuple is not unique, don't emit anything -- otherwise, emit the "head" tuple only -- this would keep the last copy of a tuple in the result. This are just ideas. Hard to give a generic answer.

Answer (score 1):

While searching for a solution for the same problem, I found the "Interval Join" very useful, which does not repeatedly output the same elements. This is the [example from the Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/joining.html#interval-join):

```java
DataStream<Integer> orangeStream = ...
DataStream<Integer> greenStream = ...

orangeStream
    .keyBy(<KeySelector>)
    .intervalJoin(greenStream.keyBy(<KeySelector>))
    .between(Time.milliseconds(-2), Time.milliseconds(1))
    .process (new ProcessJoinFunction<Integer, Integer, String(){
        @Override
        public void processElement(Integer left, Integer right, Context ctx, Collector<String> out) {
            out.collect(first + "," + second);
        }
    });
```

With this no explicit window has to be defined, instead an interval that is used for each single element like this (image from [Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/joining.html#interval-join)):

[image: interval join time graph]